# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'schoolmanagementsystem.progress_report' ( errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

My queries are as below,

```
create table Student(
reg_no int auto_increment not null primary key,
roll_no int not null,
student_name varchar(20),
Class_number int not null
);

create table Progress_report(
e_id int auto_increment not null primary key,
exam_name varchar(20) not null,
roll_no int not null ,
Class_number int not null,
subject varchar(20),
Marks int,
foreign key (roll_no) references Student(roll_no),
foreign key (Class_number) references student(Class_number)
 );
```

First table created successfully,unable to create second table.

Comment: https://aodba.com/solution-error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-mysql/

Comment: Referenced columns in foreign key constraints have to be a key (unique). `Student.roll_no` isn't, so you can't reference it in `Progress_report`.